# Startx take me root@hostname prompt with high video but no gui

Tags: command-line, gui, prompt

I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS trusty on a PowerPC.

When I first login, I got a prompt `user@hostname`

I then run `sudo startx`

It runs through the whole procedure but instead of getting the GUI desktop
I get `root@hostname` prompt.

How do I bring up the GUI?

Juan

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sudo for `startx`. Just run `startx /path/to/your/desktop-environment`. For example, I run `startx /usr/bin/openbox` or `startx $(which openbox)`.

On Ubuntu by default you don't have `.xinitrc` file, but if you want to run a specific desktop environment, you'd have to create one. For instance, on my Arch Linux install in virtual box I have `.xinitrc` file, which has `exec /usr/bin/blackbox`, thus everytime I run `startx` command it automatically launches `blackbox` desktop.

A note of caution: if you start unity with `startx unity` it will be missing top panel indicators, hence I suggest you start `lightdm` login screen first, and then login into unity.

Comment: Well when I don't run it with "Sudo" its like it runs without the proper permission or something.  I tried running "lightdm" but it says it is not installed or something,..don't remember exact words..  but again..when I do run the Startx.. it only gives me the high video mode but no desktop.. is this something I have to fix in the xorg.conf file?  I had to make modification because my KDS monitor could not support certain video modes....but now I get the high video mode but no GUI.

Comment: @JohnnyQ that is very strange. For lightdm the command is `sudo service lightdm restart` . Just out of curriosity : are you running Ubuntu desktop installation or server ? Because server installation doesn't come with gui by default.

Comment: I tried it but got unrecognized service

Comment: @JohnnyQ No need to thank, I enjoy helping people. So far not being too effective, though :) Strange, you should have `lightdm` installed by default. Are you connected to the internet ? if you are , do `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and try again that `sudo service lightdm restart` command

Comment: Ok. I did that, but I think it is not install.. I am running "sudo install lightdm" and it is processing so lets see.. I will let you know..

Comment: How do I find the path to the install?

Comment: @JohnnyQ no,no,no. Command is `sudo apt-get install lightdm`, not `sudo install lightdm`. There's no command `install` on ubuntu.

Comment: OK.. I got a GUI but installed KDM instead of lightdm

Comment: @JohnnyQ ah, ok. So can you do `sudo service kdm restart` ?

Comment: I went into the KDM GUI.. I think it is working.. and just to let you know why I am doing this.. I had a spare PPC here and did not want to buy a separate computer for Ubuntu.. I am going to try and install ROS in it..and use it for a drone programming project I am starting.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Ah, great !  Glad we got it working. I am not familiar much with drone programming, only have modest knowledge of shell scripting, c and java programming. Hopefully your project comes to fruition ! Good luck !

Comment: thank you so much for your help... and just to let you know.. if you know C & Java.. and for sure you know Linux.. then you can program drones too.. ROS is a actually a Linux based Robot Operating System.. check it out when you can.. and again.. thank you so much